# Fixed-width number formatting

Tags: python, formatting

When formatting values, the minus sign is not taken into account:

```
>>> format_len5 = lambda val : '{:5.3f}'.format(val)
>>> len(format_len5(1.2345678))
5
>>> len(format_len5(-1.2345678))
6
```

My best solution so far is to check the sign of `val` and adapt the length accordingly:

```
>>> format_len5 = lambda val : ('{4.3f}' if val<0 else '{5.3f}').format(val)
```

But this does not seem right. Is there another way to achieve fixed-length strings that does not involve the ternary operator?

Comment: Why doesn't this seem right? I think it's perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Isn't it acceptable to always use a sign? Like `'{: 5.3f}'` or `'{:+5.3f}'`

Comment: Your solution does not seem to work.

Comment: @Tim I thought I could found a value-independant string format. KillianDS's would work but wastes one char (to fit a 5-char column, I need to use `'{: 4.3f}'`).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way, without using *formatting*, is to use *slicing*:

```
format_len5 = lambda val : str(val)[:5]

print format_len5(1.234567)    #1.234
print format_len5(-1.234567)   #-1.23
```

**Note:** This will truncate the result, not round it as formatting would.

Comment: This will give an incorrect answer as it truncates the number rather than rounding.

Comment: Does formatting rounds numbers? I think both ways would lead into non-rounded numbers.

Comment: Yep, formatting will round the number. `format_len5(1.2349) == '1.235'`, `format_len5(1.2340) == '1.234'`

Comment: Another issue is bigger numbers. _Formatting_ can exceed in size, showing you the number is too big. _Slicing_ will just cut it and keep the left digits (e.g. `str(100000)[:5]` is '10000')

Comment: What would be the expected output in that case?